# How to completely uninstall and re-install Pillow?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I am trying to reinstall Pillow on my Server and I am getting this:

```
...
Proceed (y/n)? y
  Successfully uninstalled Pillow-4.0.0
(myproject)$ pip install --upgrade --force-reinstall Pillow
Collecting Pillow
  Using cached Pillow-4.0.0-cp27-cp27mu-manylinux1_x86_64.whl
Collecting olefile (from Pillow)
  Using cached olefile-0.44.zip
Building wheels for collected packages: olefile
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for olefile ... error
  Complete output from command /home/user/.virtualenvs/myproject/bin/python2.7 -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/tmp/pip-build-C7Frjt/olefile/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" bdist_wheel -d /tmp/tmpToYPN3pip-wheel- --python-tag cp27:
  usage: -c [global_opts] cmd1 [cmd1_opts] [cmd2 [cmd2_opts] ...]
     or: -c --help [cmd1 cmd2 ...]
     or: -c --help-commands
     or: -c cmd --help

  error: invalid command 'bdist_wheel'

  ----------------------------------------
  Failed building wheel for olefile
  Running setup.py clean for olefile
Failed to build olefile
Installing collected packages: olefile, Pillow
  Found existing installation: olefile 0.44
    Uninstalling olefile-0.44:
      Successfully uninstalled olefile-0.44
  Running setup.py install for olefile ... done
Successfully installed Pillow-4.0.0 olefile-0.44

(myproject)$ python
>>> import Pillow
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named Pillow
```

What am I doing wrong?

EDIT: I also tried to remove Pillow and PIL directories but I still don't get it to work:

```
(myproject)$ rm -rf PIL
(myproject)$ rm -rf Pillow-4.0.0.dist-info/
(myproject)$ pip install Pillow
Collecting Pillow
  Using cached Pillow-4.0.0-cp27-cp27mu-manylinux1_x86_64.whl
Requirement already satisfied: olefile in ./.virtualenvs/myproject/lib/python2.7/site-packages (from Pillow)
Installing collected packages: Pillow
Successfully installed Pillow-4.0.0
(myproject)$ python
Python 2.7.5 (default, Nov  6 2016, 00:28:07) 
[GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-11)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import Pillow
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named Pillow
>>>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try using and see if it works.

`import PIL`

OR

```
import PIL as pillow
from PIL import Image
```

Comment: OK, this worked. What kind of wizardry is this? The reason that I am using Pillow is because I am using sorl-thumbnail for my Django project. sorl-thumbnail and Pillow is a requirement (http://sorl-thumbnail.readthedocs.io/en/latest/requirements.html#python-imaging-library-installation). How on earth this works?

Comment: No wizardry. As per as the documentation, `Pillow is the friendly PIL fork by Alex Clark and Contributors. PIL is the Python Imaging Library by Fredrik Lundh and Contributors.`